# Having trouble making a PNG bitmap from an NSView

Tags: cocoa, png, nsview

**Update**
Nevermind :-)
Figured it out using `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect` & `cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:`.
I'll leave the question here for posterity, though.

---

I'm working on a little application that, among other things, has an `NSView` subclass that draws a bunch of bezierPaths. I'd like to be able to save the drawn result as either EPS or PNG.

The view is being drawn in an offscreen window (for scaling reasons), and even though it returns the correct EPS data, I can't seem to get any useful bitmap data from it.

EPS is no problem (I simply write the `NSData` from `-dataWithEPSInsideRect:` to a file), but I can't seem to get a PNG bitmap.

If I try calling:

```
[self lockFocus];
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:self.bounds];
[self unlockFocus];
return rep;
```

from a category method I've added to NSView, I get useless white PNG data out of it when I try `representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:[NSDictionary dictionary]`.

Strangely, if I try calling lockFocus/initBitmapWith../unlockFocus from *outside* the view (or its category methods), I get an exception saying that the view or one of its ancestors is hidden. And well, yes, it's offscreen (the offscreen window's been init'ed with defer:NO, by the way, so it should paint).

So I can either get useless data or I can get an exception. Not awesome.

To add to my confusion: If I make an NSImage containing an EPS representation, and a (useless) white bitmap, where both should be the size of the view's bounds, the bitmap representation is always 20 pixels/units narrower than the bounds. No idea why! The EPS is the correct size.

Since this may all be related to how the offscreen window's created, here's the code for that (from the NSView category)

```
- (NSWindow*)placeInOffscreenWindow {
NSRect windowBounds = { { -1000.0 , -1000.0 } , self.bounds.size };
NSWindow *hiddenWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: windowBounds
                                                         styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
                                                           backing: NSBackingStoreNonretained
                                                             defer: NO];

[[hiddenWindow contentView] addSubview:self];
return hiddenWindow;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up using `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` & `cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:` instead

Comment: Yes, and here is an answer that at least gives the actual code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9545213/478742

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create an NSImage, lock focus on it, tell the view to draw its bounds, and unlock focus, then [ask the image to create a CGImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/CGImageForProposedRect%3acontext%3ahints%3a), then pass that to a [CGImageDestination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/) to write out the PNG data/file.

Comment: @Hosey: Thanks for the tip, but I actually ended up using bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect: & cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep: instead, and that seems to work fine. But I'll probably try out your suggestion too, just to learn something. By the way, I'm using the script Rentzsch made enable your suggested warnings - thank you! "Hardass mode" gave me a ton of ideas for refactoring, so it's all a lot nicer now! Also, since I'm only starting out with Obj-C/Cocoa, it's a big, big help!

Comment: I've found CGImageDestination more reliable than NSBitmapImageRep's `representationUsingType:properties:` method, but they *should* do the job equally well. As for the warnings post: You're welcome. ☺

Comment: @Hosey: Interesting. Thanks for the insider-tip :)