# Saving entire NSView contents, which is inside an NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to save contents of an NSView as an image, but, only the image visible inside the scrollview is saved.

Here is the actual image loaded in the view:
[image: actual image].

But this is how I'm able to save the image:
[image: saved image]

Is there any way to save the entire image in the NSView?

This is how I'm saving my NSView subclass:

```
- (void)save
{
    [self lockFocus];
    NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[self bounds]];  
    [self unlockFocus];

    NSData* data = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];

    NSString* string = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString* pth1 = [string stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ttx.png"];

    [data writeToFile:pth1 atomically:YES];
}
```

This method is in the View i want to save.

Comment: @hamstergene I've edited my question with the code i'm currently using to save. Is it the right way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `-[NSView cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:]`

```
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
[self cacheDisplayInRect:self.bounds toBitmapImageRep:rep];
```

Comment: It works using these two methods! I didn't know how to use these methods before. Thanks!

Comment: Finally something that works. So many wrong, partial or problematic solutions on SO...